# Retrofit Observable HTTP requests in multiply threading

Tags: android, multithreading, http, observable

I have a list of elements.
I need to call api with every element pentameter.

```
Observable<Element[]> elementObservable = service.elementList(name);
elementObservable.toBlocking().subscribe(elements -> {
List<Element> elementList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Element element : elements) {
                    service.getElement(element.getFullname()).toBlocking()
                            .subscribe(elementList::add, e -> {

                            });
                }
    });
```

Can I somehow add multiply threading to "For" loop to make service.getElement call in multiply threads?

Comment: Stop using `toBlocking()` and upgrade OkHttp Dispatcher thread pool size

Comment: you mean elementObservable.toBlocking() ?